# Does google ever use guesses to find webpages?

Tags: url, search-engine

If I have a webpage (www.example.com/very_long_random_name.htm) on a site that's already been indexed by google, will it ever be found if it has no incoming links?

Or can google find such unlinked pages by some other method?

Comment: You can submit / block that page from being indexed through Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not be indexed. At least in theory, that is. The crucial thing is that there are no incoming links, the fact that the name is long and random does not matter.

However, it is hard to be sure that it really won't be indexed, since incoming links can come from everywhere and without your knowledge. For example some email that contains a link might get indexed (especially if one particicpant in the conversation uses a questionnable mail provider), or someone might post a link on some forum, etc.

Comment: Does GMail count as questionable? :-) Because I'm afraid it might get indexed through GMail :-)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if the chrome browser might inform google or even an ISP (when someone visits) or the hosting company for the page

Comment: I can only speak from my experience, but I've used gmail to talk about some random private (there would be no harm if there were to be indexed) applications on our server and used chrome to visit them, and none of them got indexed by google. To be sured something doesn't get index, a robots.txt is certainly better

Comment: I think the Google Toolbar is used to collect URLs.